# How to make a button stay depressed when clicked in a Swing Java GUI app

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This seems like something really simple and yet I can't find any good solutions online. I am making a simple game and in the main frame  I have JButtons. What I would like is for when I click a button it stays looking visually depressed and then when I click it again it "pops" back up. I know I need an ActionListener on the button but I can't figure out the code inside of it. I've seen some discussions referencing "setPressed(true);" but as far as I can tell that is not a method on a JButton object, so I don't know how it's useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JToggleButton`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information.